# How should I initialize an array with some objects in it?

Tags: java, json

I want to create a JSON data with two objects in an array

```
String message = "{ "animal" : [{"name":"alice", "type":"cat"}, {"name":"john", "type":"dog"}, {"name":"peter", "type":"bird"} ] }";
```

But this will make some errors and cannot run in eclipse

How can I resolve it

Comment: Your question from title (*How should I initialize an array with some objects in it?*) and question in body looks different (*How can I resolve it*), if you want to solve the Eclipse error then try this - `String message = "{ \"animal\" : [{\"name\":\"alice\", \"type\":\"cat\"}, {\"name\":\"john\", \"type\":\"dog\"}, {\"name\":\"peter\", \"type\":\"bird\"} ] }";`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape double quotes with backslashes as shown below:

```
String message = "{ \"animal\" : [{\"name\":\"alice\", \"type\":\"cat\"}, {\"name\":\"john\", \"type\":\"dog\"}, {\"name\":\"peter\", \"type\":\"bird\"} ] }";
```

Eclipse has an option "**Escape text when pasting into a string literal**" (`Preferences->Java->Editor->Typing`) that copy-paste multi-line text into String literals will result in quoted new lines. Please note that after enabling this feature you still have to first write two quotation marks and then paste your text inside those marks.

[image]

Adding the the code samples to parse your json data.

```
package com.stackoverflow.answer;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class JsonParserExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String message = "{ \"animal\" : [{\"name\":\"alice\", \"type\":\"cat\"}, {\"name\":\"john\", \"type\":\"dog\"}, {\"name\":\"peter\", \"type\":\"bird\"} ] }";
        JSONObject messageJson = new JSONObject(message);
        JSONArray animals = messageJson.getJSONArray("animal");

        int n = animals.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            JSONObject animal = animals.getJSONObject(i);
            System.out.println(String.format("animal.%d.name: %s", i, animal.getString("name")));
            System.out.println(String.format("animal.%d.type: %s", i, animal.getString("type")));
        }
    }

}
```

Hope you are clear now. It's too late. I'm going to sleep. Happy coding!!!

Comment: how can I get the data "peter" ?